# Can't connect to remote Ubuntu instance when vpn active

Tags: ssh, vpn

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04.2 DigitalOcean droplet, I have NordVPN installed on the droplet, and switch proxies regularly.

When I try and connect to my instance via SSH while NordVPN is connected on the droplet, I get time out errors and can't connect.

I'm looking for a way to access the droplet while NordVPN is running on it.

Comment: Are you using a VPN from your droplet, or your local computer?

Comment: The problem is that it replaces your default route. You should look into policy based routing, where you send different kinds of traffic into different pipes.